# Add text to beginning of line if a string is present in that line

Tags: string, text, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ and working with a huge log file of about 400MB. Is it possible to place a particular text at the beginning of a line, if a certain string is present in that particular line?
For example:

Input

```
This is a sentence
This is a sentence
This is the sentence
This is a sentence
```

I want to have the text YES in front of a line featuring the word 'the'

Output

```
 This is a sentence
 This is a sentence
 YES This is the sentence
 This is a sentence
```

Comment: I dont know if using editor but if using programming language it's simply use   looping and strpos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
(.*\bTHE_STRING\b.*)
```

**Replace:**

```
SOME_TEXT$1
```

The find pattern will match and consume the entire line, but only if the string of interest should appear.  Then, for the replacement we use your new text, followed by the entire original line.